# XML::Compile::SOAP and a fault call

Tags: perl, soap, fault

I'm having a problem trying to deal with a SOAP fault and I can't figure out if its on my end or the other end.

I'm using a WSDL file and I have the following code:

```
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;
my $wsdlXml = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file("pathtowsdl");
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdlXml);
my $call = $wsdl->compileClient('Add');
my %param = ('param1'   =>  'xxx',
             'param2'   =>  'xxxx',
             'param3'   =>  'xxxx',
             'Name'     =>  {
                'first' =>  'xxx',
                'last'  =>  'xxx',
              });
my ($response, $trace) = $call->(\%param);
```

If I call that with the correct params then everything works as you would think, $response if a hash ref that has the results I'm looking for.

If however I cause a fault, then I get nothing back. $response has nothing in it (per Data::Dumper).

The thing is, $trace DOES have the soap envelope in there. The soap envelope is there in $trace on both a success and a failure/fault but only on a success is there something in $response, on the failure the "faultType" and "faultData" that is in the envelope should be in $response.

Am I doing something wrong? From everything I've read it sounds like I shouldn't have to do anything different and in the case of a fault we should have something like $response->{'fault'}, yet like I said, $response is empty.

Any ideas of what I should be looking for?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not really an answer for your question, but I cannot post just comments yet, so here is an idea: try to use [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (they have a free version too that is enough for your goal) or similar software and test your SOAP service with it to be sure that the issue is in your code and not on the SOAP service side.

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty cool program. It seems to see the fault so I have no idea what is happening with XML::Compile